# VBA - How do exit a main sub if a condition in other subs isn't met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeking for your help. Well I have a main sub divided in a lot of other subs. I would like to stop VBA from passing to the next sub if mandatory data is missing. I have done the following:

```
Public IsExit As Boolean

Sub main()
Call DefineVariables

      IsExit = False

    Call Check_products_flows_input
    If IsExit = False Then Exit Sub
    Call check_admin
    If IsExit = False Then Exit Sub
    Call overall_product_check
    If IsExit = False Then Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

For the first sub this worked, if the first sub is being called and the sub is exited, the main is exited as well. But for the other subs this does not work. VBA sees that something is missing, gives an error box, but still continues to the next sub.

Below is the code, where VBA gives an error, go to exit sub line, but still continues with the next subs in the main module.
I have removed the first part of the code, since the code works.

```
Sub overall_product_check()
    
     'start of the loop
    For Each cell In shInput.Range("B12" & ":" & "B" & lrow)
    searchvalue = cell.Value
    Set rngfound = columnrange.Find(searchvalue)
    
    If rngfound Is Nothing Then
    
    MsgBox "Missing mandatory data or superfluous data format", vbCritical, "Invalid product type match"
        Cells(7, 5) = "The input data is not valid"
        Cells(7, 5).Font.Color = -16776961
        Cells(7, 5).Font.Bold = True
      Exit Sub
    
    End If
        
        Next cell
        IsExit = True
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: You need to change the subs into functions where they return true or false. If everything's in order return true and if something is missing return false. Then you only need to check the return value for each function.

Comment: _For the first sub this worked, if the first sub is being called and the sub is exited, the main is exited as well._ the first check `Sub `changes the value of `IsExit` to `True` and you never set it back to `False` before running next `Sub`s

Comment: The more conventional method would be to have the called Subs raise an error and have main handle those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand the comment with an example, change the Subs into Functions and check their return value.

For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    
    'Execute and exit if return value is False
    If Not overall_product_check() Then Exit Sub
       
    '...
    
End Sub

Private Function overall_product_check() As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In shInput.Range("B12" & ":" & "B" & lrow)
        searchvalue = cell.Value

        Set rngfound = ColumnRange.Find(searchvalue)

        If rngfound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Missing mandatory data or superfluous data format", vbCritical, "Invalid product type match"
            Cells(7, 5) = "The input data is not valid"
            Cells(7, 5).Font.Color = -16776961
            Cells(7, 5).Font.Bold = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'all good
    overall_product_check = True
        
End Function
```

---

You need to declare your variables. Use `Option Explicit` in all your modules.